# Pandas version is different in Anaconda Navigator and Anaconda Prompt

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, anaconda, modin

I tried importing modin in my jupyter notebook. when I run the cell

```
import modin.pandas as pd
```

I get the following warning

```
UserWarning: The pandas version installed 1.2.3 does not match the supported pandas version in Modin 1.2.4. This may cause undesired side effects!
```

I tried updating my pandas using `conda install pandas=1.2.4`, it did not work, the command prompt got stuck at 'solving environment' stage for a long time and I had to stop manually. - attached is the screen shot [Anaconda Prompt Install](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgxh5.png). I used `pip install pandas==1.2.4`, it worked. Now my anaconda prompt shows pandas version as 1.2.4, but my anaconda navigator shows 1.2.3. Attached are screenshots [Anaconda Navigator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oed4y.png), [Anaconda Prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m0NIs.png). How do I resolve this issue/use modin without any warnings?
Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thank you!

Comment: Are you installing one in the base environment and another in a different virtual env? Your screenshots do not specify the env. Also, what do you mean by "it did not work?"

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply, I updated the screen shots, I think I am looking at the same environments I am not sure what is going wrong here.

Comment: Be careful, messing with the packages in the base environment can very easily lead to a bunch of issues and is likely part of the problem here! I would recommend starting over with a fresh install of Anaconda.